# How does RxJava Observable "Iteration" work?

Tags: java, rx-java

I started to play around with RxJava and ReactFX, and I became pretty fascinated with it. But as I'm experimenting I have dozens of questions and I'm constantly researching for answers.

One thing I'm observing (no pun intended) is of course lazy execution. With my exploratory code below, I noticed nothing gets executed until the `merge.subscribe(pet -> System.out.println(pet))` is called. But what fascinated me is when I subscribed a second subscriber `merge.subscribe(pet -> System.out.println("Feed " + pet))`, it fired the "iteration" again.

What I'm trying to understand is the behavior of the iteration. It does not seem to behave like a Java 8 `stream` that can only be used once. Is it literally going through each `String` one at a time and posting it as the value for that moment? And do any new subscribers following any previously fired subscribers receive those items as if they were new?

```
public class RxTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Observable<String> dogs = Observable.from(ImmutableList.of("Dasher", "Rex"))
                .filter(dog -> dog.matches("D.*"));

        Observable<String> cats = Observable.from(ImmutableList.of("Tabby", "Grumpy Cat", "Meowmers", "Peanut"));

        Observable<String> ferrets = Observable.from(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Harvey"));

        Observable<String> merge = dogs.mergeWith(cats).mergeWith(ferrets);

        merge.subscribe(pet -> System.out.println(pet));


        merge.subscribe(pet -> System.out.println("Feed " + pet));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Observable<T>` represents a monad, a chained operation, not the execution of the operation itself. It is descriptive language, rather than the imperative you're used to. To execute an operation, you `.subscribe()` to it. Every time you subscribe a new execution stream is created from scratch. Do not confuse streams with threads, as *subscription are executed synchronously unless you specify a thread change* with `.subscribeOn()` or `.observeOn()`. You chain new elements to any existing operation/monad/Observable to add [new behaviour](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#alphabetical), like changing threads, filtering, accumulation, transformation, etc. In case your observable is an expensive operation you don't want to repeat on every subscription, you can prevent recreation by using `.cache()`.

To make any asynchronous/synchronous `Observable<T>` operation into a synchronous inlined one, use `.toBlocking()` to change its type to [`BlockingObservable<T>`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Blocking-Observable-Operators). Instead of `.subscribe()` it contains new methods to execute operations on each result with `.forEach()`, or coerce with `.first()`

Observables are a good tool because they're mostly* deterministic (same inputs always yield same outputs unless you're doing something wrong), reusable (you can send them around as part of a command/policy pattern) and for the most part ignore concurrence because they should not rely on shared state (a.k.a. doing something wrong). BlockingObservables are good if you're trying to bring an observable-based library into imperative language, or just executing an operation on an Observable that you have 100% confidence it's well managed.

Architecting your application around these principles is a change of paradigm that I can't really cover on this answer.

> *There are breaches like `Subject` and `Observable.create()` that are needed to integrate with imperative frameworks.

Comment: The one thing I'd quibble over is that an `Observable` isn't guaranteed to be deterministic. I use Observable.from(Future<T>) quite a bit to construct pipelines of operations (communicating with a serial device) such that the entire job is encapsulated as an Observable<FinalResult> that, when subscribed to, will start the sequence of requests and depending on the external state, provide a different result.

Comment: They are deterministic in the sense that for the same input they always produce the same output. If you were to create two observables out of the same future, both of them would behave identically; whereas imperative code becomes a stochastic black box every time you send a value to a different scope (method) and wait for a response because the code could depend on a shared mutable state that may have changed.

Comment: I rephrased for accuracy anyway.

Comment: Hmm, let me rephrase my own comment while I'm at it. It's true that a given future will produce the same result when constructing an observable from it. What I'm doing is (ab)using `flatMap` with `from(Future<T>)`, e.g.
`Observable.defer(() -> firmware.run(commandA)).flatMap(a -> firmware.run(commandB));` That'll return an observable, but depending on when you subscribe to it, those futures may be fulfilled differently.

Comment: So, when I've constructed that A->B pipeline, there's only one resulting Observable, but subscribing at different times (and thus causing the defer and flatmap functions to be invoked again) can have vastly different outcomes.

Comment: Yes, but it's the same case for a network operation, you use a future to fetch a value or an error. Whatever the case, once the execution finishes you'll have to relaunch it with a new future if you want a new result.

Do you reuse the same instance of a future multiple operations? My experience wit them has mostly been of single use due to their implementation in Volley.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75560/discussion-between-tom-g-and-mlprogrammer-cim).

Comment: I would quibble about the determinism as well. Say you had an Observable that just emitted a random number of random numbers, before subscribing nothing can be determined about either the number of outputs or what they would be. Otherwise, great explanation.

Comment: I can accept that things like Observable.create() and Subjects break the deterministic clause, but just because the framework has to interop with imperative languages.

Comment: But a random number in this context is the input, not the operation, so that's not an example of non-deterministic behaviour.

Comment: In RxJava the correct way to express a random number is Observable.just(Random.nextInt()), which is a deterministic Int->Int operation; rather than Observable.create(() -> { return Random.nextInt()}) which is Void->Int and relies on breaching the functional paradign.

Comment: So going back to newbie level conversation, I have been reading up on this for past two days. So the observable is "emitting" the inputted items as a list? And flatmap() would similarly convert a mapped list into a new observable that emits each item? So if interpret your answer correctly, it is doing it one at a time rather than many at a time by default, unless an executor is specified to support asynchronous emit operations?

Comment: In case of double, check the code: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/Observable.java#L1187

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/86147542573004f4df84d2a2de83577cf62fe787/src/main/java/rx/internal/operators/OnSubscribeFromIterable.java#L92

Comment: So basically it is a lot of boilerplate to hide a single Iterable operation. For every element it just gets returned, effectively separating each one of the elements. If you wanted to send the whole list, you'd use Observable.just(), which send whatever parameter as it is.