# Observables return data over time?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Im going through the angular.io docs and some other material trying to get up to speed with angular.  One thing that has not quite sunk into my head yet is observables.  Im reading this

*Observable help us to manage async data. You can think of Observables as an array of items, which arrive asynchronously over time.*
from here   https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular-http-tutorial-with-rxjs-observables/

I understand sync vs async, but this sounds as though possibly some array items arrive at different times?  Is that the case, or is it that the calling thread is allowed to continue while the that which is being observed is allowed to finish processing then resume where it left off when its ready?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does RxJava Observable "Iteration" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711347/how-does-rxjava-observable-iteration-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes with Observables some items could arrive at different times. For example, say you are observing input element value changes. The user could type, pause, and type more. So the items arrive at different times.

However, when using Observables with Http, the Observables are "one and done". This means that it gets just the one response from the backend as "one" observable entry. It can then map that one response into an array of data.

For example, say you are retrieving a set of products via Http. You will get the *entire* set of products back as one response object that is then *one* Observable in the observable sequence. That response can then be mapped into the appropriate array of product objects. But the Observable still only sees it as "one" thing.

Make sense?

Comment: DeborahK - love your Angular course on Pluralsight!  Its been a big help

Comment: So nice to hear! Thanks! I'm in the process of updating it to use the CLI and the new version 4.3 HttpClientModule and HttpClient service.

Answer (score 2):

[Observables](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/observable.md) in RxJs can observe items arriving at different times.  You can observe things such as key-strokes, where items will continue to trickle in as they happen.  You can also observe things like a single AJAX request, where you will only be getting 1 response.

There are a few distinctions to be made with Observables:

---

[Hot vs. Cold Observables](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2604)

In short, with cold observables, when you subscribe to them, you are triggering an action.  An example would be an AJAX request.  The request will not fire until the observable is subscribed to.

---

Finite Observables:

Observables will be either finite or infinite.  A finite observable (such as an AJAX request) will invoke the subscription's complete callback when it is done.  Other observables, such as observing keyDown events, will only end when it is unsubscribed from.  These will continue to invoke the onNext callback every time there is a keydown event.